# Функция newRow в C#5

Tags: c#

> Объясните, пожалуйста, 1)newRow это метод использующийся для создания строки или ячейки? ведь метод не обязан заполнять все ячейки строки, тогда строка получается не полная. 2) Что тогда в остальных ячейках null? Также не ясно 3) при добавлении table.Rows.Add(newRow) newRow это также ф-я или это очередь из строк/ячеек? Получается, что все newRows должны где-то хранится. 4) Где они хранятся? И правильно ли понимаю, 5)они добавляются в том порядке и количестве котором создавались?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

// Создание строки для таблицы и добавление ее в коллекцию строк объекта DataTable

namespace BasicsDataRow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(int)));
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2"));


            DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();

            newRow["Column1"] = 1; // индексатор объекта DataRow в качастве строкового индекса принимает имя поля в строке к которому нужно обратиться
            //newRow[0] = 1;

            newRow["COlumn2"] = "One";
            //newRow[1] = "One";          // индексатор объекта DataRow в качастве целочисленного индекса принимает индекс поля в строке к которому нужно обратиться

            Console.WriteLine("table.Rows.Count: " + table.Rows.Count); // выведется 0

            table.Rows.Add(newRow); // строка становится строкой таблицы при добавлении её в коллекцию Rows таблицы

            Console.WriteLine("table.Rows.Count: " + table.Rows.Count); // выведется 1

            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", column.ColumnName, row[column]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) А как, собственно, метод-то называется? "Row" это строка или ячейка по-вашему? 2) Что вам мешает посмотреть это с помощью дебагера? Очевидно, что там будет значение по-умолчанию 3) `newRow` - это переменная, а не функция. `NewRow` - это метод объекта типа DataTable, инициализирующий новый экземпляр DataRow с аналогичной схемой. `Add` - метод объекта типа DataRowCollection, который экземпляр DataRow добавляет, собственно, в коллекцию. 4) После добавления DataRow в DataRowCollection там она и "хранится" 5) Нет, конечно. Все добавляется в том порядке, в котором вы это и добавляете ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: C# 5 - ой, плохо. Сильно устаревшая версия. Пользуйтесь более новыми учебниками и документацией. Сейчас доступна версия C# 8. Идёт работа над девятой. PS: хотя в ADO.NET с тех пор ничего особо не поменялось, поэтому непосредственно в этом вопросе версия языка не важна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае newRow это переменная хранящая в себе ссылку на объект экземпляр класса DataRow она же запись в таблице.  Созданная фабричным методом из таблицы NewRow. Таблицы если ввести аналогию с матрицей то строки - это записи, а столбцы - это колонки их пересечение ячейка.  А то что там null по умолчанию это так его фабрика создаёт. Table.Row.Add добавляет в конец коллекции.